# Splitting symbols from a file

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python, I've wrote a function that reads a file and that strips odd symbols out of the file.

```
def clean_string(x):
    return x.strip().strip('"').strip("'").lower()
```

and to read the file

```
with open(fileName, 'r', errors='replace', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    urls = []
    for line in data:
        cleanName = clean_string(line.split(',')[0])
        cleanServer = clean_string(line.split(',')[1])
        name = request.quote(cleanName.encode('utf-8'))
        server = request.quote(cleanServer.encode('utf-8'))
        url = baseUrl.replace('<name>', name).replace('<server>', server)
        urls.append(url)
```

While cleanName works perfectly, I'm getting list index out of range for cleanServer, when I print the line with [1] index, it also prints the output, which means the index exists, what am I doing wrong?

Example data:

```
"Bicmex"
,"ravencrest"
"Fleshcraft"
,"archimonde"
"Satanå"
,"stormscale"
"Jàgër"
```

Comment: How exactly is your input data formatted? If it's as you've shown you will run the loop on each line of the file (i.e. `"Bicmex"`) not each pair (`"Bicmex","ravencrest"`) which I think is what you are trying to do?

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, i.e. when `line` is `"Bicmex"`, `line.split(',')` results in `['"Bicmex"']`, and `['"Bicmex"'][1]` is indeed out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains a line without server. You need to check for that and f.e. print that line:

Fix:

```
with open(fileName, 'r', errors='replace', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    urls = []
    for line in data:
        splits = line.split(',', 1)  # maximal 2 parts, no need to split twice
        cleanName = clean_string(splits[0])
        name = request.quote(cleanName.encode('utf-8'))
        if len(splits) == 2:
             cleanServer = clean_string(splits[1])
             server = request.quote(cleanServer.encode('utf-8'))
             url = baseUrl.replace('<name>', name).replace('<server>', server)
             urls.append(url)
        else:
             print(f"No Server given: '{line}'")
```

This would work for files like:

```
"Bicmex","ravencrest"
"Fleshcraft","archimonde"
"Satanå","stormscale"
"Jàgër"
```

To handle files that have alternating lines, use:

```
with open(fileName, 'r', errors='replace', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.readlines()

data = ''.join( zip(data[::2], data [1::2])
```